# Proper way to manage long-running feature branch that may need multiple rebase actions?

Tags: git, rebase

I understand that you are not supposed to push changes to your remote until after you rebase, and I *sort of* understand why.  However, envision the following scenario:

- make feature branch
- do work
- rebase
- push and file pull request
- all good, right?  wrong!  integration manager rejects your feature with comments
- make repairs to your feature
- meanwhile, master has moved on, so you rebase again...
- oops!  now you are rebasing a branch that was already pushed!

What is the right way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

> "*you are not supposed to push changes to your remote until after you rebase*"

I completely disagree with this statement; none of what you are describing should warrant a rebase.

The problem that you are describing makes it sound like you **only** have a `master` branch on your remote, and that you have been branching feature branches off of this. This goes against **[Git Flow](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html)**.

**Don't worry** about long-running feature branches -- this is perfectly normal, and you're perfectly fine to repeatedly push such a branch to `origin`. This is even recommend due to the backup in Git (which you mentioned).

You'll want to follow the typical Git Flow:

1. You have a `master` branch hooked up to your production environment,
2. You branch `develop` off of your `master` branch
   (and hook this up to development and testing environments).
3. You branch each of your `feature` branches off of **`develop`**, not `master`,
4. At any time, whether the feature is complete or not, you make a commit to `origin/feature/your-branch`,
5. When that feature is complete, you merge to `develop` through a pull request.
   **THIS is the only place where conflicts should occur!**

   - If there are conflicts, you fix them on your **local** branch, by `pull`ing the `develop` branch into your local feature branch. You may need to `stash` your changes first. You can then `push` your local branch back to `origin` -- the feature branch won't have been merged yet.
   - After conflicts have been resolved, the branch gets merged into `develop`.
6. `develop` then gets deployed out to your development environment (preferably automatically through a Continuous Integration tool such as Jenkins or TeamCity). This way the development environment always has all of the latest features.

[image: Feature branches]

7. When you have thoroughly tested your feature(s), you create a release cut of the features, and release that version to `master` (which gets deployed to production). It's also beneficial to add a `tag` onto the branch at this point, so you know exactly which version is currently in production.

[image: Release cut]

This way you won't ever have have a situation where pushing your code to `origin/feature/your-branch` causes any sorts of problem to any other developer or environment before a merge. It also means that after the feature is merged into `develop`, your production environment still won't contain the feature, so you don't need to worry; you're free to test the feature before the feature hits the production server.

Comment: Your discussion of environments and production servers implies an assumption of the type of project we are working on.  We don't have any of those things.  I'm mainly just looking for best practices on Git, agnostic to the type of project being worked on.  I'll attempt to interpret your answer as it applies to our domain.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you don't have various environments -- though it is certainly standard to have (at least) three separate environments for development, testing and production. If you only have one environment, the same principles apply -- simply treat your environment as production, and only ever deploy there once you are ready for the public to see it (and all features have been tested). You'll want the same branch flow. You'll have to get testers to manually check out the `develop` branch at the specific point you want to make a release. If it's good, merge **that commit** to `master`.

Comment: I think I am starting to see the light on this.  I was exposed to a few articles in a row, that had me convinced `rebase` was the way to go, but it seems, especially for a newer team like ours, `merge` is a lot safer and easier to understand.